# Macro works in Word 2013, but not in 2010

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

I wanted to create a template for my fellow workers and create a Macro which "Saves As.." to a specific file, and also uses the title to suggest the name.

Somehow the Macro ignores the location for the destination and opens the standard "Documents" folder

This is solved, thanks to the following code!

```
Sub FileSave()
'
' FileSave Macro
' Het actieve document of de actieve sjabloon opslaan
'

   ChangeFileOpenDirectory _
        "F:\Company\Marketing\Voorstellen\Voorstellen\Voorstel\"

        If ActiveDocument.Path = "" Then
        ' If the document has never been saved, the
        ' value of its .Path is an empty string; otherwise
        ' it has the file's path and name.
        With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
            .Name = MakeDocName  ' call the function below
            .Show                ' the suggested name will be in the dialog
        End With
    Else
        ' The document has already been saved with a name
        ' so just save it there.
        ActiveDocument.Save

       End If

End Sub


 Function MakeDocName() As String
    Dim theName As String
         Trim(ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Title"))
    MakeDocName = theName  ' return the assembled name
End Function
```

Comment: are getting any Errors?

Comment: No, nothing seems to happen. Like the entire Macro doesn't start.
I updated the trust center

Comment: It works in my Word 2010. I bet the reason is that the hardcoded location at `F:\` is causing trouble here.

Comment: Oke, I'm going to try it in location 'C:', maybe the problem lies in the fact that it is an Microsoft Exchange server location.

is there a solution for this?

Comment: Omar; I tried it with and without the backslash and also on the 'C:' location. It did not work, most likely because it is done on a Microsoft Exchange server, on the shared location.

We do have an Excel 2010 Macro running on it, and that one works just fine.

Comment: What I do not understand although you said it worked in 2013: your `With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks` block does nothing! Also, are you trying to concatenate `theName` with the `Trim()` part? because you don't. :-?

Comment: LocEngineer: 
What worked was; 
Open the "Save As.." DialogBox and it showed the specific folder in which it had to be saved.
 
The entire name part, didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed all the non-operative part of your MakeDocName function and this worked just fine for me in Word 2010 (also note the capital T in Title property:

```
Function MakeDocName() As String
    Dim theName As String
        theName = "C:\00_Projects_temp\" & Trim(ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Title"))
    MakeDocName = theName  ' return the assembled name
End Function
```

Comment: P.S: For the name thing to work, the document must have a value in Title property, that does not contain invalid characters for file names of course!

Comment: Thank you, it worked on the 'C:' location!
I'm trying it on the 'F:' location now.

Comment: Great, the Macro works for opening the "Save As.." DialogBox in the right 'F:' folder!

However, I made a Word document and saved it as a template with macro's. When I click the Template, it opens the template in stead of a new document.

Still lots of thank you's for everyone who helped so far!

Comment: Uh, that's not how templates work. It should open a new document based on that template - provided you double click it. It only opens the template if you say "File=>Open" and pick the template from there.

Comment: Yeah I know, it just went wrong somewhere. Now I solved the Template problem, it opens a new document, but now the macro fails..

It completely ignores the 'F:' destination, and just opens the standard "Documents" folder

Comment: Works for me. How are you calling the macro? Problem must be in the calling.

Comment: FileSave is it called

Comment: I mean how do you activate it? With a button? Or via Developer tools=>Macros=>Macros in [yourtemplate].dotm?

Comment: Developer tools=>Macros=>Macros in [yourtemplate].dotm

This way

Comment: That's weird. I just tested it with mine, altered the path in the template, saved, double clicked, ran the macro: voilà, new path. Stupid question but: are you sure your F path is properly mapped on the machine you are trying this (accessible for the logged on user)?

Comment: I really think the problem lies within the F: Directory.

I tried a ChDir for the SaveAs part, but without succes.

Btw: I owe you many thanks man, for helping out so far!

Comment: Does the path exist? Sure there are no typos? Play it safe, browse to the destination with Explorer and copy the path from the address line. Oh: and make sure you have the trailing backslash. That is really needed!

Comment: Loc Engineer:

This code worked!

It was mainly your corrections, included an extra trailing backslash at the end of the directory and included a part under Sub.

 ChangeFileOpenDirectory _
        "F:\Company\Marketing\Voorstellen\Voorstellen\Voorstel\"

This made it work on my own computer and also on the pc's of my fellow workers

I'll put the entire code in the original post! You really saved the day!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **`(\)backslash`**

```
theName = "F:\Company\Marketing\Voorstellen\Voorstellen\Voorstel\"
```

To

```
theName = "F:\Company\Marketing\Voorstellen\Voorstellen\Voorstel"
                                                           ^'suggested Name = Voorstel
```